# Date difference in Hours format from bigint in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime, datediff, bigint, date-difference

I have a column of `bigint` type containing date & time information (like `1353056515`, `1353067040`, `1360839600` etc.)

My requirement is to get time difference in HOURS format between column which I mentioned above and current datetime.

I tried to find the solution, but those were so confusing. I'm new to SQL Server.

Please help.

Comment: If it's a date&time information - why isn't it stored properly, in a `DATETIME` column? That's what they're there for! Also: *how* is the date&time "mangled" ("encoded") into this `bigint` format?? What do these numbers represent?

Comment: The datetime format is added by a plugin which i installed on my website. So i cant change their format or do any changes. Also i have no idea how they encoded.

Comment: If you don't know how the date is encoded, how do you expect to get the difference between two encoded dates? What plugin did you use? Did you check its documentation? Asked the authors how they encode time? Is it a UNIX timestamp?

Comment: i have used WizIQ plugin. I'll contact them to find more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this.

```
declare @mydate datetime
DECLARE @LocalTimeOffset BIGINT
  ,@AdjustedLocalDatetime BIGINT

SET @LocalTimeOffset = DATEDIFF(second,GETDATE(),GETUTCDATE())
SET @AdjustedLocalDatetime = 1416474000 - @LocalTimeOffset

SELECT DATEADD(second,@AdjustedLocalDatetime, CAST('1970-01-01 00:00:00' AS datetime))
-- It will give you date 2014-11-20 14:30:00.000
```

The data difference operation:

```
select DATEDIFF(hour,@mydate,GETDATE())
```

or

Create Function

```
create  FUNCTION dbo.fn_ConvertToDateTime (@Datetime BIGINT)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @mydate datetime
  DECLARE @LocalTimeOffset BIGINT
           ,@AdjustedLocalDatetime BIGINT

  SET @LocalTimeOffset = DATEDIFF(second,GETDATE(),GETUTCDATE())
  SET @AdjustedLocalDatetime = @Datetime - @LocalTimeOffset
  SELECT @mydate=DATEADD(second,@AdjustedLocalDatetime, CAST('1970-01-01 00:00:00' AS datetime))
  return @mydate
END;
GO

select mydate= dbo.fn_ConvertToDateTime (1416474000)

select DATEDIFF(hour,@mydate,GETDATE())
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have added i date (11/20/2014 10:00:00 AM) from front-end and it is showing as 1416474000 in DB. And when i tried your query, its showing the result as 393056 Hrs. It must be less than 12 hrs when current time is 2014-11-20 01:57:09.670 on server. Am i doing some thing wrong ?

Comment: if  it is not working than do the needful Change Your Column Type set as DATETIME It Will make Easier to Get Hour Difference its not solution but alternate option ...

Answer (score 0):

The number looks like a UNIX timestamp, which is the number of seconds since 1/1/1970 00:00:00 UTC. You can get the UNIX timestamp from a `datetime` with a simple DATEDIFF:

```
declare @date datetime='2014-11-20T10:00:00'
declare @epoch datetime='19700101'

select DATEDIFF(s,@epoch,@date)
```

To get the number of hours between two timestamps you simply need to divide the difference by 3600 (the number of seconds in an hour). You don't need to convert the timestamps to dates before calculating the difference :

```
declare @dateTS int=DATEDIFF(s,@epoch,@date)
declare @nowTS int=DATEDIFF(s,@epoch,GETUTCDATE())

select (@nowTS-@dateTS)/3600.0
```

Note that I used `3600.0` to get a decimal result. If `3600` is used the fractional part will be truncated and you'll get `0` for differences less than 1 hour. This is OK if you want to return whole hours.

In a query you could write something like this:

```
select (DATEDIFF(s,@epoch,GETUTCDATE())-[MY_TS_COLUMN])/3600.0 AS Hours
from [MY_TABLE]
```